# How to flip "start" game button to "pause" game, while also allowing keycode 80 (p) to pause the game as well

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, pause

As of now, all I know to be certain is to set the global variable of 'paused' to be false. Adding an eventlistener and updating my loop function, etc. is where I am uncertain on implementation, otherwise the game is "finished" by all means!

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
canvas.width = 1280;
canvas.height = 700;
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
let obstacles = [];
var cancelMe = '';
let difficulty = 10;
let id;
let dis = 0;
let miles = 0;
let paused = false;

function getScore() {
    let highScore = localStorage.getItem('highscore');
    console.log('highscore is ', highScore);
    document.getElementById('score').innerHTML = 'Highscore: ' + highScore + ' ft.';
}
getScore();

function saveScore(score) {
    let highScore;
    if (!isNaN(localStorage.getItem('highscore'))) {
        highScore = localStorage.getItem('highscore');
    } else {
        highScore = 0;
    }
    console.log(highScore);
    highScore = Math.max(score, highScore);
    localStorage.setItem('highscore', highScore);
}

var img = new Image();
img.src = './images/background.jpg';
img.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
};

var durianImg = new Image();
durianImg.src = './images/durian.png';

durianImg.onload;

var backgroundImage = {
    img: img,
    x: 0,
    speed: -1.5,

    move: function() {
        backgroundImage.x += this.speed;
        backgroundImage.x %= canvas.width;
        sprite.distance += 0.2;
    },

    draw: function() {
        ctx.drawImage(this.img, this.x, 0);
        if (this.speed < 0) {
            ctx.drawImage(this.img, this.x + canvas.width, 0);
        } else {
            ctx.drawImage(this.img, this.x - this.img.width, 0);
        }
    }
};

var timeFalling = 0;

function clamp(num, min, max) {
    return num <= min ? min : num >= max ? max : num;
}

var sprite = {
    name: 'Mr. Sprite',
    x: 2,
    y: 528,
    distance: 0,
    int: null,
    moveLeft: function() {
        sprite.x -= 30;
        sprite.x = clamp(this.x, 0, 1280);
        sprite.distance -= 30;
    },
    moveRight: function() {
        sprite.x += 30;
        sprite.x = clamp(this.x, 0, 1230);
        sprite.distance += 30;
    },
    moveUp: function() {
        if ((sprite.y = 528)) {
            sprite.y -= 70;
            this.beginFall();
        }
    },

    beginFall: function() {
        clearInterval(this.int);
        timeFalling = 0;
        this.int = setInterval(function() {
            timeFalling = timeFalling + 1;
        }, 10);
    },
    draw: function() {
        spriteImg = new Image();
        spriteImg.src = './images/sprite.png';
        ctx.drawImage(spriteImg, sprite.x, sprite.y, 50, 60);
    },
    fall: function() {
        if (this.y < 528) {
            this.y += 9.8 * timeFalling / 150;
        } else {
            clearInterval(this.int);
            this.y = 528;
        }
    }
};

class obstacle {
    constructor(x, y, width, height) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

    fall() {
        if (this.y < 528) {
            this.y++;
        }
    }
}

document.onkeydown = function(e) {
    switch (e.keyCode) {
        case 37:
        case 65:
            sprite.moveLeft();
            console.log('left', sprite);
            break;
        case 38:
        case 87:
        case 32:
            sprite.moveUp();
            console.log('right', sprite);
            break;
        case 39:
        case 68:
            sprite.moveRight();
            console.log('right', sprite);
            break;
    }
};

function checkCollision(obstacle) {
    if (obstacle.y + 60 > sprite.y && obstacle.y < sprite.y + 60) {
        if (obstacle.x + 50 < sprite.x + 50 && obstacle.x + 50 > sprite.x) {
            console.log('Collision');
            gameOver();
        } else if (obstacle.x < sprite.x + 41 && obstacle.x > sprite.x) {
            console.log('Collision');
            gameOver();
        }
    }
}

function updateCanvas() {
    backgroundImage.move();

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    backgroundImage.draw();

    dis++;
    if (dis % 20 == 0) {
        miles++;
    }
    ctx.fillStyle = '#606060';
    ctx.fillText('Distance Traversed: ' + miles + ' ft.', 540, 40);
    sprite.draw();
    sprite.fall();

    if (dis % 40 == 0) {
        obstacles.push(randomObstacle());
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < obstacles.length; i++) {
        obstacles[i].draw();
        obstacles[i].fall();

        checkCollision(obstacles[i]);

        if (obstacles[i].y > 520) obstacles.splice(i, 1);
    }
}

function startGame() {
    difficulty = Number(document.querySelector('#diffSelect').value);
    id = setInterval(updateCanvas, difficulty);
    startGameButton.disabled = true;
    init();
    loop();
}

var startGameButton = document.getElementById('startGameButton');
startGameButton.onclick = startGame;

function restartGame() {
    clearInterval(id);
    obstacles = [];
    var timeFalling = 0;
    sprite.x = 2;
    sprite.y = 528;
    sprite.distance = 0;
    sprite.int = null;
    dis = 0;
    miles = 0;
    fallSpeed = 1.0005;
    startGameButton.disabled = false;
    ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
    ctx.font = '18px serif';
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    backgroundImage.draw();
    audio.pause();
    location.reload();
}

var retryGameButton = document.getElementById('retryGameButton');
retryGameButton.onlick = restartGame;

ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
ctx.font = '18px serif';

function randomObstacle() {
    let x = Math.random() * canvas.width;
    let y = 0;

    return new Durian(x, y);
}

let fallSpeed = 1.0003;

setInterval(function() {
    fallSpeed += 0.0008; // tweak this to change how quickly it increases in difficulty
    // console.log(fallSpeed);
}, 8000); // timer at which it gets harder

class Durian {
    constructor(x, y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    draw() {
        ctx.drawImage(durianImg, this.x, this.y, 50, 60);
    }
    fall() {
        if (this.y < 528) this.y = (this.y + 1) ** fallSpeed;
        this.x -= 1.5;
    }
}

var hotbod = document.querySelector('body');

function doStuff() {
    hotbod.className += ' animate';
}

window.onload = function() {
    doStuff();
};

function gameOver() {
    clearInterval(id);
    ctx.fillStyle = '#606060';
    ctx.font = '70px Anton';
    ctx.fillText('GAME OVER', 430, 300);
    console.log('save ', miles);
    saveScore(miles);
    audio.pause();
    new Audio('sounds/game_over.wav').play();
}

function init() {
    audio = document.getElementById('audio');
    // add listener function to loop on end
    audio.addEventListener('ended', loop, false);
    // set animation on perpetual loop
    setInterval(animate);
}

function loop() {
    audio.play();
}
```

And for my index.html where the buttons are displayed:

```
        <div id="menu">
            <div class="custom-select instruct">
                <select id="diffSelect">
                    <option value="6.5">Easy</option>
                    <option value="5.5">Medium</option>
                    <option value="4.5">Hard</option>
                    <option value="3">Extreme</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <input id="startGameButton" type="button" class="instruct" onclick="startGame()" value="Start" />
            <input id="retryGameButton" type="button" class="instruct" onclick="restartGame()" value="Reset" />
            <p class="disclaimer">DISCLAIMER: Once you wipe out, hit reset & change to a higher difficulty if you dare, then hit start to play again!</p>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following
*btw any `...` represents your code I didn't include to save space*

```
...
let gameRunning = false;
...

document.onkeydown = function(e) {
    switch (e.keyCode) {
        case 80:
            if(gameRunning) { 
                paused = !paused;
                startGameButton.value = paused ? "Un-Pause" : "Pause";
            }
            break;
        ...
    }
};

...

function startGame() {
    if(gameRunning){ 
        paused = !paused; 
        startGameButton.value = paused ? "Un-Pause" : "Pause";
    }
    else {
        difficulty = Number(document.querySelector('#diffSelect').value);
        id = setInterval(updateCanvas, difficulty);
        gameRunning = true;
        startGameButton.value = "Pause";
        init();
        loop();
    }
}

...
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply so much! However, no luck :\ I put a console.log('Paused) above the if statement for case 80, and it is logging it however, just not implementing it.

Comment: any errors in console? is `gameRunning` set to true when you are clicking `p`? Also I JUST edited my code, I moved `gameRunning` & `startGameButton.value` to run *before* it runs `init` & `loop`.

Comment: Okay so 1 error:
```
index.js:134 Uncaught ReferenceError: paused is not defined
    at HTMLDocument.document.onkeydown (index.js:134)
```
But the button now does switch to say "Pause," but pressing it or "p" doesn't pause the game or flip the button to "Un-pause".
I tried declaring let paused = ''' as a global variable at the top, which didn't help solve the problem, but it did allow me to click the "Pause" button and it toggled to "Un-pause."

Comment: Odd, I just tried the code on a JS fiddle, and everything is working correctly.(except a few bugs due to some missing assets) Can you share a link to your current code?

Comment: Yes here's my repo: https://github.com/neekyo/Durian-Dodger
Thanks for your continued help!

Comment: so sorry it's taken so long to reply, been busy. But I believe the problem was we had `startGameButton.disabled = true` when we first clicked the start/pause bttn. If you remove that line it should fix it.

Comment: No prob, I appreciate any help! Still throwing an error though :(
```index.js:201 Uncaught ReferenceError: paused is not defined```
I just updated my remo to make sure it's up-to-date!

Comment: your repo doesn't have the line: `let paused = false;` like shown in your question.

Comment: jeez im so sorry for this taking so long haha, i added that back in and it triggers the button, as well as pressing p, but it just doesn't actually pause the game now. no errors in console!

Comment: well then you're question should be solved. You now have the variable `pause` as well as a button that swaps text based on that. To *actually* pause the game is for you to figure out.

Comment: just wanted to let you know it has finally been done!
just added this one damn line to the beginning of my update function and all my frustration is finally gone! 

```function updateCanvas() {
 if (paused) {
  return;
 }```